# Can I run Baldur's Gate on my Windows 7 computer?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, baldurs-gate

I have heard that there are some technical problems with running Baldur's Gate on a computer with Windows 7, but the Virtual Machine I have sucks, because the mouse pointer is always flickering. What I want to know is, if I install Baldur's Gate, will my computer have any problems?

Comment: Just sayin' http://store.steampowered.com/app/228280/

Answer (score 15):

According to [Good Old Games](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/baldurs_gate_the_original_saga/) these are supported OS:

> Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7
>   (32 & 64 bit)

They have also a [list](http://www.gog.com/en/support/baldurs_gate_the_original_saga) of issues and possible solutions.

Comment: Good Old Games versions of classic games often feature fixes and updates that make older games work better with newer operating systems.  If installing the original game, it may not work as well.  Buying the GOG version is often the most stress-free way to go, even for those that may already own a copy of the game.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, I'm currently running baldur's gate 1 & 2 (all expansions) on my 64 bit copy of windows 7.  I set the compatability flags to windows XP and it works great.  Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't noticed any issues running on Win7 - it's just the usual matter of setting compatibility flags and the like.

Also, regardless of whether you get it working or not, installing Baldur's Gate won't break anything else on your machine.

Comment: Oh ok thank you I had been scared for a while there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition` just released on Steam: http://store.steampowered.com/app/228280/

It has updated graphics and works perfectly on Windows 7

Comment: It works on Windows 7 and 8. I'm using the Beamdog version.

Answer (score 1):

It should run fine if you run it in compatibility mode, like the others said.

However, if you have an NVIDIA card, you may experience a graphical glitch which makes the covered parts of the maps look odd.

This link has some workarounds for it (culminating in an unofficial patch if all else fails - which I have used and works a treat)
http://blog.yimingliu.com/2008/04/16/baldurs-gate-1-graphics-glitch-and-disabling-nvidia-hardware-acceleration/

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh thanks i do have an nvidia card this was my second problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you also own BG2, I definitely suggest using BG1tutu (in the EasyTutu flavouring) to play BG1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the game in a folder other than C:\Program Files(x86) to avoid issues with UAC. I'm able to run BG2 without using compatibility mode.